# Cheap privacy oriented cell phones

Tags: privacy, smartphone

What are cheap (<200 USD) and privacy oriented cell phones ?

I am looking for the phones just for calling and sms messaging. I consider phones with and without operating system, or I can buy one of both types. But I do not accept situation when my OS is linked to Google like classic Android does. Is there Android version that is not preinstalled with Google services ? What are the alternatives for Android ? Can I buy any cell phone and reinstall choosen OS ?

I have heard that Nokia 3310 is good way but it is easily to break with fake BTS attack.

Then, any smartphone have operating systems that make possible to attack our device with many new ways. I learned about BlackBerry which one was privacy oriented. But probably already working with United States duties. And recently produce cell phones with preinstalled Google version of Android... Blackphone is too expensive...

I think to buy an old Nokia 3310 for some special situations and one cheap and safe smartphone with some safe OS for everyday use. What do you think ? Should I buy Nokia 3310 from some people (used) who have got it 15 years ago or can I buy one brand new (old version of 3310 but not used one) from aliexpress (from Chinese) ? They sell brand new Nokia 3310 (and it is not a new version of Nokia 3310 which is widely being sell).

Comment: Welcome to Information Security SE, Unfortunately your question is about product recommendations which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CopperheadOS is an Android fork, that is all about security. It can be installed on Pixel devices and some Nexus devices. It may however be quite expensive to get those.

Lineage OS is another android fork, that is nowhere near as secure and security is not even its main goal, however it does not contain any google services and has many security and privacy features. It also supports wide variety of devices, making it a lot cheaper option and one that is more user friendly (allows stuff that copperhead does not for security reasons).

Comment: CopperheadOS has lost its main (only) developer recently when the CEO tried to take absolute control. Its developer even deleted the signing keys because he no longer trusts it. I would not use CopperheadOS...